# Equality between topologies can be ensured if connected components are same?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty set. Suppose that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two topologies over $X$, such that $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$.
Which of the following statements imply that $\tau_1 = \tau_2$?

1. $(X,\tau_1)$ is compact and $T_2$ (Hausdorff)
2. $(X,\tau_1)$ is compact, $(X, \tau_2)$ is $T_2$ (Hausdorff)
3. The connected components of both $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(X,\tau_2)$ are same
4. For any subset $A \subset X$ the closure of $A$ in $(X,\tau_2)$ is contained in the closure of $A$ in $(X,\tau_1)$

See that (1) need not be true from the trivial topology and discrete topology on a finite set. (2) is true since the identity map from $(X,\tau_1)$ to $(X,\tau_2)$ is continuous. What about (3) and (4) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$ implies that $\operatorname{Cl}_{\tau_1}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}_{\tau_2}(A)$ as the right hand side is a $\tau_2$-closed, hence $\tau_1$-closed, superset of $A$ and the $\tau_1$-closure is the minimal one. So $(4)$ than states that the other inclusion also holds, giving the topologies the same closed sets and so $(4)$ implies $\tau_1 = \tau_2$.

The components being equal is too coarse: If $\tau_1$ is the discrete, and $\tau_2$ the usual topology on $\Bbb Q$, then the inclusion (but not equality ) holds while both sets have as components all sets $\{q\}$ where $q \in \Bbb Q$.